# wxwidgets debug crt function not included error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, wxwidgets

Would anyone be able to explain why i would be getting a fatal error? I have searched all over and it seems that i cannot find a solution.

I am trying to build a project with WXwidgets and when i build my project i keep getting fatal error 1189 debug CRT functions not included.

I have already built and released the wxwidgets project.

I am programming in c++, and using visual studios 2015.  Basically I would like to understand why this error is occurring and how i could fix it.

> C:wxWidgetsTemplate.2.5.3\build\wxWidgetsNuGetCreatePCH.cpp(33): fatal error C1189: #error:  Debug CRT functions have not been included!
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: are you able to build the minimal sample or any other samples successfully with provided solution?

Comment: I have tried to compile the samples but I get a different error when I try.  I must not be including everything correctly.

Comment: do not change anything in the solution or the code. Just open it and compile. Also, how do you compile the library? Just open the appropriate solution, then go to "Build->Batch Build...", select all and click "Build"

Comment: If you have not built wxWidgets as monolithic, are you including the required libraries.